# How to get values from an Adapter Class in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

I'm trying to get data dynamically from an Adapter Class but I don't know how to do it.

What I want is to get if the CheckBox (`cardCheck`) is checked when the "Calculate" Button at the bottom is clicked.

Here is a picture of the layout of the app
[image: img1]

Code of **Card** (Model)

```kotlin
package com.bhasvic.gardener.models

data class Card(var name: String, var price: Int, var checked: Boolean)
```

Code of **Adapter Class**

```kotlin
package com.bhasvic.gardener.adapters

import android.annotation.SuppressLint
import android.content.Context
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.CheckBox
import android.widget.EditText
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.bhasvic.gardener.models.Card
import com.bhasvic.gardener.R

class CardAdapter(private val ctx: Context) : RecyclerView.Adapter<ServicesViewHolder>() {
    private val messages: ArrayList<Card> = ArrayList()

    @SuppressLint("NotifyDataSetChanged")
    fun addMessage(message: Card){
        messages.add(message)
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return messages.size
    }

    fun getItem(position: Int): Card {
        return messages[position]
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ServicesViewHolder {
        return MyServicesViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(ctx).inflate(R.layout.card, parent, false))
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ServicesViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val message = messages[position]
        holder.bind(message)
    }

    inner class MyServicesViewHolder(view: View): ServicesViewHolder(view) {
        private var cardName: TextView = view.findViewById(R.id.cardName)
        private var cardPrice: EditText = view.findViewById(R.id.cardPrice)
        private var cardCheck: CheckBox = view.findViewById(R.id.cardCheck)

        override fun bind(message: Card) {
            cardName.text = message.name
            cardPrice.setText(message.price.toString())
            cardCheck.isChecked = message.checked
        }
    }
}

open class ServicesViewHolder(view: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
    open fun bind(message: Card) {}
}
```

Code of **Main Activity**

```kotlin
package com.bhasvic.gardener

import android.annotation.SuppressLint
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.bhasvic.gardener.adapters.CardAdapter
import com.bhasvic.gardener.models.Card


val services = listOf("A", "B", "C")
val services_prices = listOf(11, 7, 22)

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    @SuppressLint("InflateParams", "StringFormatMatches")
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        // Define the variables
        val cardsList = findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.cardsList)
        val buttonCalculate = findViewById<Button>(R.id.buttonCalculate)

        // Define the Card
        val cardAdapter = CardAdapter(this)
        cardsList.adapter = cardAdapter

        // Add the Services
        for (item in services.indices) {
            val toAdd = Card(name = "Services: ${services[item]}", price = services_prices[item], checked = false)
            cardAdapter.addMessage(toAdd)
        }

        buttonCalculate.setOnClickListener {
            val itm = cardAdapter.getItem(0).checked.toString()
            Toast.makeText(this, itm, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `Adapter` is just a class that takes *some data* and displays it in *some widget*. You've already created a function to add items to the data set (`addMessage`), why not just make one to grab the data you want?

```
fun getCheckedMessages(): List<Card> = messages.filter { it.checked }
```

or if you really do just want to get the checked status of the first item:

```
fun isFirstItemChecked() = messages.firstOrNull()?.checked ?: false
```

---

Also, you're not actually storing the checked status of an item when the user toggles it (by setting `message.checked`). It's just a checkbox that gets set when it's first displayed, then the user can turn it on and off but it doesn't do anything. Typically you'd make the `ViewHolder` keep a reference to the current data item it's displaying, and add a listener on the checkbox during init, something like this:

```
    inner class MyServicesViewHolder(view: View): ServicesViewHolder(view) {
        private val cardName: TextView = view.findViewById(R.id.cardName)
        private val cardPrice: EditText = view.findViewById(R.id.cardPrice)
        private val cardCheck: CheckBox = view.findViewById(R.id.cardCheck)

        // reference to the message we're displaying
        // lateinit because we don't have one yet, but we'll set it before it's used
        private lateinit var currentMessage: Card

        init {
            // you want an onClick listener instead of an onCheckedChangeListener,
            // just because updating the checked state would trigger it - probably
            // fine here, but it can cause problems with observer/reactive patterns
            cardCheck.setOnClickListener { checkbox ->
                // update the current message to match the state of the checkbox
                message.checked = checkbox.checked
            }
        }

        override fun bind(message: Card) {
            // keep a reference to this message so it's the one that gets updated
            currentMessage = message

            cardName.text = message.name
            cardPrice.setText(message.price.toString())
            cardCheck.isChecked = message.checked
        }
    }
```

Comment: the function `getCheckedMessages()` doesn't return anything

Comment: and what if I change the cardName? how do I get a list of all of them in order

Comment: @Slimakoi I'm not sure what you're asking me - that function I wrote is how you return all the items in ``messages`` that have ``checked = true``. If it's returning nothing, then none of them are set as checked. (Like I pointed out, you're not actually setting that value, your checkbox is currently decorative). It returns them in the order they appear in the list, you can use ``sortedBy { it.name }`` or whatever if you want to sort the results

Comment: what if for example, I put stuff inside the `EditText` box and get the data from it?

Comment: @Slimakoi then you need to set up a listener (e.g. a ``TextWatcher``) on your ``EditText``, and update your dataset to reflect the contents of that widget when appropriate. So you'd do that in your ``ViewHolder``, because that class represents an item view that holds (in your case) a name, price and checked state, and you basically need to store that state as the user interacts with it. The data set is your source of truth, the UI is just a way to display/interact with it. And in a ``RecyclerView``, if you scroll the list enough, a ``ViewHolder`` will be reused and lose any UI state it had

Comment: How would I make that `ViewHolder` could you please guide me? Thanks

Comment: @Slimakoi it's basically the same approach as the example I gave - set listeners on your UI components in the view holder, and make them update your internal data. If you have a checkbox that reflects some ``active`` property on an item in your dataset, update that property when the box is clicked. If there's some text that can be edited, use something like a ``TextWatcher`` to store the current contents when appropriate. Then all you have to worry about is displaying the current dataset, and saving/restoring it when necessary to persist your data.